# grpc_tools.protoc generates python files with broken imports

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

I am trying to use gRPC in Python.
I have the following directory layout:

```
Oracle
|
│   setup.py
│
└───oracle
    │   oracle_server.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───generated
    │       oracle_pb2.py
    │       oracle_pb2_grpc.py
    │       __init__.py
    │   
    │
    └───protos
            oracle.proto
```

where I ran

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I ../protos --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../protos/oracle.proto
```

in `Oracle/generated`.

**Problem:**

`Oracle/oracle/generated/oracle_pb2_grpc.py` starts with

```
# Generated by the gRPC Python protocol compiler plugin. DO NOT EDIT!
"""Client and server classes corresponding to protobuf-defined services."""
import grpc

import oracle_pb2 as oracle__pb2
```

and that second import fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oracle_pb2'` when I import `oracle_pb2_grpc.py` from anywhere outside `Oracle/oracle/generated`, for example with a

```
from oracle.generated import oracle_pb2_grpc
```

in
`Oracle/oracle/oracle_server.py`.

**Question:**

Am I doing something wrong? Can I add an argument to the call of `grpc_tools.protoc` such that it generates imports that work in my setup?

(The example on https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld doesn't run into this problem because it has all files in the same directory. That's not flexible/clean enough for me)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that treating the 'generated' folder as a package is leading to broken imports. I recommend adding the scripts path using sys.path.append().

Answer (score 0):

grpc is generating python2 imports, use

```
2to3 -n -w *
```

in the output directory to change to python3